# Sorting a JSON using keys in Java

Tags: java, json, sorting

I have JSON Object (Java), which is some key value pairs. My main objective is to use `JSONObject.toString()` and get the result in sorted orders w.r.t Keys.

Is there anyway by which I can achieve this.

```
jsonObject.put("z","A");
jsonObject.put("x", "B");
jsonObject.put("n", "C");
jsonObject.put("t", "D");`
```

Expected Output of `jsonObject.toString`

```
{"n":"C","t":"D","x":"B","z":"A"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i sort my JSON object based on Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493413/how-can-i-sort-my-json-object-based-on-key)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992966/java-sort-json-string-using-key)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca In this case I have doubt on solution of Christian, as I need  output of JSONObject.toString in sorted order.

Comment: Yes, I misread your question before you edited it. The answer to the second link seems more in line with what you want.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for the Second Solution, its working perfectly fine.